# Wait 6 hours after milk?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, chabad

I once came across someone who was avoiding the meat at a lunchtime simcha.  When I asked him why, he said it was because he had eaten "cereal with milk" at breakfast.  When I expressed confusion, since as far as I understood only "hard cheese" (whatever your interpretation of that) requires waiting before eating meat, he replied that he received his practice from Chabad.

Is this really a known Chabad practice?  If so, what is the source?  I am leaning toward him being misinformed (or perhaps misrepresenting the true reason he wasn't eating the meat).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is definitely not a known Chabad practice. See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30483&st=&pgnum=316&hilite=) where the Lubavitcher Rebbe would wait at least one hour after eating milk on Shavuos to start eating the Yom Tov meal (that included meat). As the footnotes elaborate, he was against any leniency (as others hold) with regards to Shavuos and waiting times, and this custom of waiting an hour was a practice by the Chabad Rebbes which may or may not be applicable to the Chassidim in general.

In practice, Lubavitchers that I know generally wait an hour, sometimes a half hour and fairly rarely not at all.

Answer (score 8):

The Zohar in parshas Mishpatim makes no difference which type of food was eaten first in the requirement to wait to eat the other type. This Zohar is quoted in the Biur HaGra in Yo'd 89 #6 as a source for the minhag recorded in the Ramma to wait six hours after meat. The fact that this Zohar would require six hours after milk too is ignored by the Gra but raised as a question in other places. Also of note, the Zohar never mentions the amount of time to wait as six hours. And the actual intent of the Zohar is not so clear, see the Pri Chadash who says the same idea as the Gra and see the Kreisi & Plasey where he argues on the Pri Chadash.

However, I have never heard of anyone ruling like this. Chabad included.

Answer (score 5):

[Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/133896/jewish/Waiting-Periods-Between-Meat-Dairy.htm) does not mention anything regarding waiting 6 hours after eating milk. The only time it requires this is when eating certain hard cheeses.

> After eating dairy and before eating meat, eat something pareve, which
>   does not stick to the palate. Then rinse your mouth, or take a drink,
>   and wash your hands. In addition, many have the custom of waiting a
>   certain period of time -- a half-hour or an hour. After eating certain
>   hard cheeses, a six-hour waiting period is required

Answer (score 2):

I think that he means that he waited 1 hour

http://www.shturem.net/index.php?section=artdays&id=1513

> ו. בין אכילת חלב לבשר יש להמתין לכל הפחות שעה אחת (אוצר מנהגי חב"ד, סיון, עמ' שז אות כג סק"ג).‏

There is a zohar which writes (פרשת משפטים דף קכה א):

"דכל מאן דאכיל האי מיכלא (בשר וחלב) דאתחבר כחדא, או בשעתא חדא או בסעודתא חדא, ארבעין יומין אתחזיא גדיא מקלסא בקלפוי..." (פרוש: יראה בעור בשרו צורת גדי מקולס שדי שיכירוהו כוחות הטומאה להעניש)‏

One possible explanation would be that it is not allowed to eat milk and meat in the same hour.

There was a custom in hungary to wait 30 minutes between milk and meat.

The most prevalent minhag is not to wait and just to clean the mouth and hands. This fits also best with the gmara in chulin

Comment: Except that it was well beyond one hour from breakfast time... he was in a yeshiva with a schedule... breakfast would have been about 3 hours before this simcha

Comment: Where's the "פרוש" a quotation from?

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/19586

Comment: @DesertStar the general custom is only 1 hour for milk. However, there have been rabbanim who were very broad with their descriptions of what forms of Milchiks require a 6 hour wait.